# How should I unit test multiple required fields in C#?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

Imagine this simple scenario: I have a class called `MyModel`:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string Prop01 { get; set; }
    public string Prop02 { get; set; }
    public string Prop03 { get; set; }

    public bool IsValid()
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Prop01) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(Prop02) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(Prop03))
            return false;

        return true;
    }
}
```

As, you can see, if any of the properties on `MyModel` is null or empty, the `IsValid()` method will return `false`, in other words, all the fields are "required".

I wrote some **Unit Tests** to test the `IsValid()` method:

```
[TestMethod]
public void MyModel_Invalid_When_Prop01_Is_Null()
{
    var myModel = new MyModel();
    Assert.AreEqual(myModel.IsValid(), false);
}

[TestMethod]
public void MyModel_Invalid_When_Prop02_Is_Null()
{
    var myModel = new MyModel();
    Assert.AreEqual(myModel.IsValid(), false);
}

[TestMethod]
public void MyModel_Invalid_When_Prop03_Is_Null()
{
    var myModel = new MyModel();
    Assert.AreEqual(myModel.IsValid(), false);
}
```

Of course all those tests will pass, but I'm not quite happy with that. Let's imagine I'm a developer that saw the `MyModel_Invalid_When_Prop01_Is_Null` test (that was writen by another developer). I would expect that just by assigning a value to the `Prop01` of `myModel`, the test should start failing. But of course it won't happen, so I changed the tests to look like this:

```
[TestMethod]
public void MyModel_Invalid_When_Prop01_Is_Null()
{
    var myModel = new MyModel();
    myModel.Prop02 = "Some value";
    myModel.Prop03 = "Some value";

    Assert.AreEqual(myModel.IsValid(), false);
}

[TestMethod]
public void MyModel_Invalid_When_Prop02_Is_Null()
{
    var myModel = new MyModel();
    myModel.Prop01 = "Some value";
    myModel.Prop03 = "Some value";

    Assert.AreEqual(myModel.IsValid(), false);
}

[TestMethod]
public void MyModel_Invalid_When_Prop03_Is_Null()
{
    var myModel = new MyModel();
    myModel.Prop01 = "Some value";
    myModel.Prop02 = "Some value";

    Assert.AreEqual(myModel.IsValid(), false);
}
```

Now the tests are **really** testing that each of the properties are filled, but if I add a `Prop04` to `MyModel`, that is also required field, I would need to change all my Unit Tests again, so I don't think this is a good idea.

So my question is: **How can I unit test multiple required properties in a way that I'm sure the test is either passing or failing because of that specific property I'm currently testing?** Or maybe, **Should I be testing those scenarios?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of starting with an empty, invalid model, you could start with a valid one and then make it invalid. That will make sure you only have to modify your tests in one place, which is fine, because your actual requirements changed.

An added advantage is that your tests become more explicit, because the setup is explicitly making your model invalid:

```
[TestMethod]
public void MyModel_Invalid_When_Prop01_Is_Null()
{
    var myModel = getValidModel();
    myModel.Prop01 = null;    
    Assert.AreEqual(myModel.IsValid(), false);
}

[TestMethod]
public void MyModel_Invalid_When_Prop02_Is_Null()
{
    var myModel = getValidModel();
    myModel.Prop02 = null;

    Assert.AreEqual(myModel.IsValid(), false);
}

[TestMethod]
public void MyModel_Invalid_When_Prop03_Is_Null()
{
    var myModel = getValidModel();
    myModel.Prop03 = null;

    Assert.AreEqual(myModel.IsValid(), false);
}

MyModel getValidModel() => 
    new MyModel
    {
        Prop01 = "Some value",
        Prop02 = "Some value",
        Prop03 = "Some value",
    };
```

If your model initialization becomes more complex, you could make use of the builder pattern.
I wrote a blog-post about this which may be helpful: https://www.kenneth-truyers.net/2013/07/15/flexible-and-expressive-unit-tests-with-the-builder-pattern/

Comment: Very nice! Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Glad to help! *Please upvote/accept the answer if it helped you

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, if `isValid()` is important enough to be a method then it's important enough that its behavior should be tested.

In some ways the simplicity of its logic may lull you into feeling it can't be worth all the work.  Well, I get it, but the counter-argument is if someone adds another required field, failing to update `isValid()` is a very plausible mistake; and if you're not testing the behavior if `isValid()` then you won't know until some mysterious production bug where nobody thinks to look for Prop04 to be Null because hey, `isValid()` returns true...

So yes, I'd test it; but yes, you can make that easier.  You could create a single helper function in your test class that produces a dummy instance of the `MyModel` with all fields populated.  Then your test methods just look like

(Pardon any code typos; I'm not at a compiler but I think you'll see what I mean...)

```
[TestMethod]
public void MyModel_Invalid_When_Prop01_Is_Null()
{
    var myModel = getMyModelInstance();
    myModel.Prop01 = Null;

    Assert.AreEqual(myModel.IsValid(), false);
}
```

And of course you'd have another test method that *doesn't* set any of the properties to Null and asserts that `IsValid()` should return true.

So now you add a new property, you add a new test method (which you'd expect to have to do).  You update the helper to populate the new property; you'd need that to support the "`IsValid()` is true" case anyway.  And so none of the other existing test methods needs updating.